# Implementing onClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, implementation

So I'm trying to implement the `OnClickListener` in my class but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. The point of this class is to have two 'buttons' one is a `TextView`, the other a `ImageView`. When the `TextView` is clicked, the image becomes visible (set as 'gone' from the start). Then when the image is clicked it returns to it's gone state. 
When I do it without implementing the onClick class,I get it to work perfectly but I'd rather use the implementation to make it easier for my self since I'm going to do the same thing with  multiple images.
here's my java:

```
TextView shrimp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shrimp);
    final ImageView shrimp1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stmSrimp);


    shrimp.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);


    shrimp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            shrimp1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    shrimp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            shrimp1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.shrimp:
        shrimp1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }
```

As you can see, the top part is how I originally using the `OnClickListener`, and the last part is where I tried using the implementation and I get an error on the `shrimp1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` (shrimp1) part. What the hell am I doing wrong? Should I be referring to the image by some other way?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: shrimp1 cannot be resolved.

Comment: Oh, because it's declared inside of a method (assuming `onCreate()`). Declare it outside of `onCreate()` and initialize it inside. It's out of scope

Comment: Correct, So lemme see if that'll fix it.
I got it, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your class (probably is an Activity) must implements the interface [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html). And then, set this class as the listener like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView shrimp;
    ImageView shrimp1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        shrimp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shrimp);
        shrimp1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stmSrimp);
        shrimp.setOnClickListener(this);
        shrimp1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

   switch (v.getId()){
   case R.id.shrimp:
          shrimp1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   break;
}
```